# How to add a ref to a 1 header file in the Makefile

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile

To refer to a folder containig header files (.h) I add the following line to my Makefile

```
CFLAGS+=-I/any/folder/include/
```

Now I want to refer to only one file in the folder.

I tried

```
CFLAGS+=-I/any/folder/include/any.h
```

But it does not work

How I can refer to only one header file in a folder?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=gcc+include+file

Comment: What do you mean "refer to a header"? What do you want `make` to do with the header?

Comment: @juanchopanza I want that my c code see only the any.h file and not other header files in the same folder because there is a risk of collusion with other folder

Comment: @MOHAMED Since that is your actual problem, add that to the question. (It's totally unrelated to makefiles, by the way.)

Answer (score 2):

You can't really grant visibility to single header files out of folders containing other files using plain `gcc` compiler flags.

A better to avoid header collisions would be to put the relevant headers in a folder with a meaningful name, e.g.

```
/any/folder/include/foo
```

Then add `/any/folder/include` to the include search path

```
CPPFLAGS += I/any/folder/include
```

and in your source code

```
#include "foo/any.h"
```

Answer (score -1):

If using GCC:

```
CFLAGS += -include /path/to/file.h
```

For MSVC:

```
CFLAGS += -FI path/to/file.h
```

That will include `file.h` at the begging of every source file compiled with those `CFLAGS`.

---

EDIT: Since I now understand what you are trying to do:

Just change the order in which headers are passed to the compiler, putting that one at the end. So it will search all the others first.

Comment: This is one of those options from the poison cupboard that make for *really* fun debugging sessions. </sarcasm>

Comment: if you want to be *really* sarcastic, put the emphasis on *fun*.

Comment: @DevSolar So is having ambiguous header includes in the first place. I'd like to assume the OP knows what they are doing, and just want some input on the technical details of the compiler commands. :)